# How to view SUM in price format?

Tags: php, pdo, sum

I am using a PDO SUM statement to total the prices of items in a checkout page, I can get the correct result but if there is an item under 1.00 for example 0.70, it displays 0.7 instead of 0.70

So is there a way I can format it correctly?
Thanks,

Here is my PHP...

```
<?php
 $res5 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS totPrice, username FROM checkout WHERE username = '$userdetails' AND cancelopt = ''");
 $res5->execute();
 $totalprice = $res5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 round($totalprice, 2);
?>


<?php echo $totalprice['totPrice']; ?>
```

Comment: Have a look at [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hi, thanks, I am testing it now but I am getting "expects parameter 1 to be float, array given" error I am doing like this `$seeit = number_format($totalprice);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @KIKO Software said :

try number_format

```
<?php
$res5 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS totPrice, username FROM checkout WHERE username = '$userdetails' AND cancelopt = ''");
$res5->execute();
$totalprice = $res5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo \number_format($totalprice['totPrice'], 2);
?>
```

Comment: `number_format($totalprice['totPrice'], 2);` this worked perfectly, thankyou! I was formatting it incorrectly